# No intellisense for xamarin forms shared project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, intellisense

I've been working on my Xamarin.forms project for a couple of weeks now and been managing to live with my intellisense problems, but as the project grows, it's getting to the point now where it's becoming a real hindrance to my work.

I'm getting no xaml intellisense (something I've seen quite a few people complain about), though far more importantly, in my shared project I'm getting very limited C# intellisense. Intellisense is picking up objects in the system namespace like string, List, Exception, EventArgs etc., but that's pretty much it. No intellisense for Xamarin.Forms objects, anything I've created in my shared project (unless it's in the same file as the code calling it), also not picking up objects in my portable class library or other 3rd party libraries like Newtonsoft.Json.

I've already tried completely reinstalling visual studio 2017, though this has had no effect.

Could someone please help me with this?

James

**edit**

I just followed this guide (https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Diagnosing-Project-System-Build-Errors) and found that my xamarin android project is loading with the following error:

Build FAILED.

C:\Users\JamesC.MJM-NORTH\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\XamarinTest\SalesOrderPage.xaml : error : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

I'm really confused what could be causing this, since the file path is clearly well under 260 characters in length, and just in case it helps here's the markup inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinTest.SalesOrderPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Sales Order Menu" FontSize="24" HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="PickBtn" Text="Pick" Image="delivery_export.png" Clicked="PickBtn_Clicked" />

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="PackBtn" Text="Pack" Image="package_export.png" Clicked="PackBtn_Clicked" />
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Per edit: I recommend moving the project folder to something as close to root as possible. `C:\src\MyProject` or somesuch is usually my go-to. The fully-qualified name length issue crops up during build because (IIRC) the java compiler spits out some really long file names and creates a deeper folder structure. So, the issue is not where your file lives, but where the output/compiled file lives. Inspect the `/bin` folder to see this. If it's easier, you could also just change the output path for your android project under Project Properties

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Joe, though I did already actually run a script to get the full file path length of every file in the project and even though some were pretty long, none exceeded the length specified. Since posting this. I've actually just decided to give up and create a new project using PCL rather than a shared project which I'm currently in the process of moving all my existing code into. I don't know if using PCL has anything to do with it, but this new project is giving me full intellisense

Comment: Jason Smith, lead product developer for Xamarin.Forms, agress that PCL is the way to go ;) Good luck! http://xfcomplete.net/general/2016/01/19/pcl-or-shared-project/